# How to separating args of a function in a script string into array

Tags: javascript

Here I have a string like :

```
var text = "hello('baby', 'i', 'love', 'you', 123);";
```

if I want write a function to process this string, and I want it return:

```
function yeah(text) {
    ....
}
```

I want `yeah(text)` return an array `['baby', 'i', 'love', 'you', 123]`, so what's the best way to write this function yeah() ?

Comment: When you say that you want to return `['baby', 'i', 'love', 'you']`, do you mean that you want to return the string "['baby', 'i', 'love', 'you']" or that you want to return an array that is set up like: `['baby', 'i', 'love', 'you']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just take the string from the first occurrence of  `(` to the last occurrence of `)` and then split it and unquote the strings:

```
function yeah(text){
    return text.substring(text.indexOf('(') + 1,  text.lastIndexOf(')'))
      .split(/,\s*/)
      .map(function(s){
        return !isNaN(s) ? +s : s.substring(1, s.length - 1);
      });
}
```

Comment: Wait... why did you add a "map"?

Comment: @Neal To unquote the strings. Your answer gives the array `["'baby'", "'i'", "'love'", "'you'"]` as mine did until I just realized that.

Comment: Ahh, I see. pretty good :-) Mind if I borrow that to add to my answer?

Comment: @Neal Nice. Works great now :) +1

Comment: since your code works great with `var text = "hello('ba)by', 'i', '(o)ve', 'you',6);";`, but could you please explain whats the `map` doing here ?

Comment: @Phoenix it removes the single quotes.

Comment: Hi @Phoenix  Without the map the result has the strings quoted an extra time. So you still get an array of strings as a result, but each string has an extra quote at the beginning and end. the map is used to remove that. Note that if you want compatibility with IE 8 and haven't already done so, you would need to implement a SHIM for `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: @Neal thanks! but I wonder why it didn't cut a numberic arg off

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks ! I just found that this is not work if there is some numberic args more than 2 digits like `"hello('I', 'have', 365, 'apples')"`, it cut 365 to 6

Comment: @Phoenix I see. In your example you only had strings before. It is an easy fix though. One sec. I'll edit

Comment: @Phoenix I have updated it now, so that it works with numbers and strings.

Comment: @Paulpro thanks!! talemyn's answer is really pretty but yours is more safer :D

Comment: @Phoenix Yeah, if you know in advance that your strings only contain `\w` (word) characters I could go with his answer. If your strings can contain spaces and such then it might be better to use mine. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for an array, the most straightforward way of doing it is:

```
function yeah(text) {
    return text.match(/\w+(?=')/g);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function yeah(text) {
    //remove start parenthesis
    var t = text.split("(");

    //remove end parenthesis
    var u = t[1].split(")");

    return u[0].split(", ").map(function(s){
       //remove single quotes
        return s.substring(1, s.length - 1);
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/T9qdA/

Answer (score -1):

One cool way you can do it is by having a function named `hello`

It would work like this. You have your string `var text = "hello('baby', 'i', 'love', 'you');"`

then you have a function like this:

```
function hello(){
  return arguments;//['baby', 'i', 'love', 'you']
}
```

to use it the code would be something like this

```
var text = "hello('baby', 'i', 'love', 'you')";
var messageArray = eval(text);//['baby', 'i', 'love', 'you']
```